Default Value Fields on Import Not Showing
According to the user guide, it should be possible to set a default value for a field when setting up an import mapping, eg Financial Type (not likely to be present in an external report) could be set to Donation for every row.
However, the default value fields shown in the user guide do not exist in CiviCRM. Is this a feature that needs to be enabled or which has been removed since the user guide was written?

Do you have the civi-import extension enabled? I think it's only enabled on new installs, so if it's an older install you'll need to enable it to get that feature. It's a core extension so it should be in your list of extensions.

Ah, good question.  I was assuming that we did, given that we have been running imports and we can go "Import Contacts" and "Import Contributions", but now I look, it's not obvious that Civi-Import is installed. Is that how it would look? thanks.
